# How to delete a row from table by using a button inside the row using html?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, database

[my screnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inob3.png)

I'm trying to create a table from a database, and I want to make a button to delete the correspondent row.

How can I do it?

```
<tr>
    <td>
    <code><?php echo $row['id_act'];?></code>
    </td>

    <th><?php echo $row['titre_act'];?></th>
    <th><?php echo $row['description_act'];?></th>
    <th><?php echo $row['date_debut_act'];?></th>
    <th><?php echo $row['date_fin_act'];?></th>
    <th><?php echo $row['pub_act'];?></th>
    <th><a href="#" class="button button-border button-MINI button-rounded button-red" onClick="javascript:getid()"><i class=""></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="button button-border button-MINI button-rounded button-green"><i class=""></i></a></th>
</tr>
```

In addition, every row gets an 'id' from the database dynamicaly

Comment: Can you show the javascript funciton`getid()`

Comment: Do you want to remove it from database or just while displaying it?

Comment: actually i didn't create that fonction (getid()), i just wanted it to be that way. i m looking for what it could be.

Comment: i want to remove it from database

Answer (score 0):

Change delete button html like

```
<a href="#" class="button button-border button-MINI button-rounded button-red deleteRow" data-id="<?php echo $row['id_act'];?>"><i class=""></i></a>
```

Now function to delete row

```
$(document).on("click", ".deleteRow", function (e) {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var tr = $(this).parents("tr");
   //Ajax call for delete row
      $.ajax({
        url:url     
        method:'post',
        data:{"id":id},
        success:function(data){
           if(data){
              tr.remove();
           }
        }
    });
```

});